# How to retrieve data from axios and fill it into an edit Form (select options) in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nestjs

I have a Form, which makes it possible to edit an user. For that, the data of an user object (by id) is retrieved by axios and is displayed in the input fields. There is no problem with input fields and the datepicker - so the information is displayed. But the data is not displayed in the select fields. I want to display the previous selected options (I got an other form, where you can create an user. The ID of the user is passed through props.), but I get an error as follows:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "bundeslaender" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

The same error I get for `vorgesetzten`. Also it should be possible to change the selected options.

The Vue component is implemented as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container>
      <h2>Benutzer bearbeiten</h2>
      <b-form @reset="onReset" @submit.prevent="saveBenutzer" id="form">
        <b-form-group
          id="input-group-2"
          label="Benutzername:"
          label-for="input-2"
        >
          <b-form-input
            type="text"
            id="input-2"
            v-model="Benutzer.Benutzername"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group id="input-group-3" label="Passwort:" label-for="input-3">
          <b-form-input
            type="password"
            id="input-3"
            v-model="Benutzer.Passwort"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group id="input-group-4" label="Vorname:" label-for="input-4">
          <b-form-input
            type="text"
            id="input-4"
            v-model="Benutzer.Vorname"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group id="input-group-5" label="Nachname:" label-for="input-5">
          <b-form-input
            type="text"
            id="input-5"
            v-model="Benutzer.Nachname"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group
          id="input-group-6"
          label="Geburtsdatum:"
          label-for="input-6"
        >
          <b-form-datepicker
            id="input-6"
            v-model="Benutzer.Geburtsdatum"
            placeholder="Geburtsdatum auswählen"
            required
          ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group id="input-group-7" label="Email:" label-for="input-7">
          <b-form-input
            type="email"
            id="input-7"
            v-model="Benutzer.Email"
            required
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group
          id="input-group-8"
          label="Betriebszugehörigkeit seit:"
          label-for="input-8"
        >
          <b-form-datepicker
            id="input-8"
            v-model="Benutzer.Eintrittsdatum"
            placeholder="Datum auswählen"
            required
          ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group
          id="input-group-9"
          label="Bundesland:"
          label-for="input-9"
        >
          <b-form-select id="input-9" v-model="Benutzer.bundesland" required>
            <b-form-select-option
              v-for="bundesland in bundeslaender"
              :key="bundesland.BundeslandID"
              v-bind:value="bundesland"
            >
              {{ bundesland.Name }}
            </b-form-select-option>
          </b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group label="Zusätzliche Rolle:">
        <b-form-checkbox id="input-10" v-model="Benutzer.istVorgesetzter"
          >Vorgesetzter</b-form-checkbox
        >
        <b-form-checkbox id="input-11" v-model="Benutzer.istAdmin"
          >Admin</b-form-checkbox
        >
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group
          id="input-group-11"
          label="Vorgesetzter:"
          label-for="input-11"
        >
          <b-form-select id="input-11" v-model="Benutzer.Vorgesetzter" required>
            <b-form-select-option
              v-for="vorgesetzter in vorgesetzten"
              :key="vorgesetzter.BenutzerID"
              v-bind:value="vorgesetzter"
            >
              {{ vorgesetzter.Vorname + " " + vorgesetzter.Nachname }}
            </b-form-select-option>
          </b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Speichern</b-button>
        <b-button type="reset" variant="secondary">Abbrechen</b-button>
      </b-form>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { server } from "../helper.js";
export default {
  name: "editBenutzer",
  data() {
    return {
      BenutzerID: null,  
      Benutzer: {
        Benutzername: "",
        Passwort: "",
        Vorname: "",
        Nachname: "",
        Geburtsdatum: "",
        Email: "",
        Eintrittsdatum: "",
        bundesland: "",
        istAdmin: false,
        istVorgesetzter: false,
        Vorgesetzter: ""
      }
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.BenutzerID = this.$route.params.id;
    this.getBenutzer();
    /*this.getBundeslaender();
    this.getVorgesetzten();*/
  },
  methods: {
    onReset(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
        this.Benutzer.Benutzername = "";
        this.Benutzer.Passwort = "";
        this.Benutzer.Vorname = "";
        this.Benutzer.Nachname = "";
        this.Benutzer.Geburtsdatum = "";
        this.Benutzer.Email = "";
        this.Benutzer.Eintrittsdatum = "";
        this.Benutzer.bundesland = "";
        this.Benutzer.istAdmin = false;
        this.Benutzer.istVorgesetzter = false;
        this.Benutzer.Vorgesetzter = "";
      this.$router.push({ name: "benutzerverwaltung" });
    },
    getBenutzer(){
        axios.get(server.baseURL + '/benutzer/' + this.BenutzerID).then(response => 
        { this.Benutzer = response.data });
    },
    saveBenutzer() {
      let benutzerdaten = {
        Benutzername: this.Benutzer.Benutzername,
        Passwort: this.Benutzer.Passwort,
        Vorname: this.Benutzer.Vorname,
        Nachname: this.Benutzer.Nachname,
        Geburtsdatum: this.Benutzer.Geburtsdatum,
        Email: this.Benutzer.Email,
        Eintrittsdatum: this.Benutzer.Eintrittsdatum,
        bundesland: this.Benutzer.bundesland.BundeslandID,
        istAdmin: this.Benutzer.istAdmin,
        istVorgesetzter: this.Benutzer.istVorgesetzter,
        Vorgesetzter:
          this.Benutzer.Vorgesetzter.Vorname + " " + this.Benutzer.Vorgesetzter.Nachname,
      };
      this.updateBenutzer(benutzerdaten);
    },
    /*updateBenutzer(data) {
      axios.put(server.baseURL/customer/update?customerID=${this.id}`,
          customerData
        )
        .then(data => {
          router.push({ name: "home" });
        });
    },*/
    getBundeslaender() {
      axios
        .get(server.baseURL + "/bundesland")
        .then((response) => { this.bundeslaender = response.data });
    },
    getVorgesetzten() {
      axios
        .get(server.baseURL + "/benutzer/vorgesetzter?istVorgesetzter=true")
        .then((response) => { this.vorgesetzten = response.data });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Show a component code and how you get data from `axios` and store it to a component data

Comment: I added the code for the Component.

Comment: No, don't add `getBundeslaender` and `getVorgesetzten` as computed because they are async. You should call them something in `created` or `mounted` hook

Comment: Sorry, I meant created and not computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define `bundeslaender` and `vorgesetzten` in data section.

It should be like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      BenutzerID: null,  
      bundeslaender: [],
      vorgesetzten: [],
      Benutzer: {
        Benutzername: "",
        Passwort: "",
        Vorname: "",
        Nachname: "",
        Geburtsdatum: "",
        Email: "",
        Eintrittsdatum: "",
        bundesland: "",
        istAdmin: false,
        istVorgesetzter: false,
        Vorgesetzter: ""
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! I added bundeslaender: [] and vorgesetzten: [] and also this.getBundeslaender(); and this.getVorgesetzten(); in the computed section and the errors are not displayed anymore, but the previous selected options are still not displayed.

Comment: Should `bundesland` field be a string or an object?

Comment: `bundeslaender` is an array of objects, so `bundesland` is an object, yes. `vorgesetzten` is also an array of Benutzer objects, but in Vorgesetzter only the Vorname and Nachname of that object is saved as a String and is passed to axios (you can see it at this line:  `Vorgesetzter: this.Benutzer.Vorgesetzter.Vorname + " " + this.Benutzer.Vorgesetzter.Nachname`. This (edit) form looks exactly like the create Form. Only the save function is different because of the axios url.

Comment: I see. `v-bind:value="bundesland"`means you want to save the whole object as selected in `Benutzer.bundesland`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: But the object in `Benutzer.bundesland` is not the same one as in `bundeslaender` even if they have the same content. You should either save an id from this object and change `:value` to indicate on `id` field of objects in `bundeslaender` array or you should find an object in `bundeslaender` array and store it in `Benutzer.bundesland`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem with the `Benutzer.bundesland` selection. But I don't have a solution for the `Benutzer.Vorgesetzter` selection or is it similar to the problem with `Benutzer.bundesland`?

Comment: The same I suppose

Comment: The problem is, that Benutzer.Vorgesetzter is only a string of an Benutzer Object (it consists of Benutzer.Vorname and Benutzer.Nachname) and is only a Benutzer where istVorgesetzter = true..

Comment: You can define compurted prop with an array based on `vorgesetzten` with a combined field